# Can't pass URI variable using prefix in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel

```
Route::prefix('{locale}')->group(function () {
    //do something with $locale
    echo $locale;
    Route::get('/', [HomeController::class, 'index']);

});
```

I get

> ErrorException
> Undefined variable: locale

How do I use the $locale variable with this method?

Comment: it doesn't work this way ... there are no actual groups, all routes are registered individually, the group is just a way to cascade configuration

Comment: try to change it, try creating group first & then set the group with prefix of your locale `Route::group(['prefix' => '{locale}'], function() {` or try like this `Route::prefix('{lang?}')->group(function() {`

Comment: I'm still getting the same error, what should they change? Can you give a complete answer?